# Plot blocking in RStudio?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to execute a function which plots some data then plays some audio (corresponding to that data) in RStudio. However, it seems that the audio playback blocks the plotting. Why is this?

```
plot.prod.df <- function(df, row) {
  # given a row number and a df, plot the prod df for that trial
  # create data
  print(paste0("plotting production data. trial: ", row))
  if(is.null(df$prod[[row]])){
    stop("Invalid trial")
  } 
  else {
    
    # get relevant production data
    prod.df <- data.frame("onset" = df$prod[[row]]$onset * 1000, 
                          "pitch" = df$prod[[row]]$pitch,
                          "error" = df$prod[[row]]$error_boolean)
    
    prod.df$error <- as.factor(prod.df$error)
    
    # get target notes
    target.notes <- str.mel.to.vector(df$stimuli.pitch[[row]], "-")
    
    # check if there were playbacktimes
    print(df$playback.times[[row]])
    if (any(is.na(df$playback.times[[row]]))) {
      print("no playback times on this trial")
      # plot
      ggplot(prod.df, aes(x=onset, y=pitch, color = error)) +
        theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = target.notes, color = magma.colors[4], size = 2, alpha = 0.7) + 
        geom_point() +
        scale_color_manual(values=c(magma.colors[1], magma.colors[2]))
    }
    else {
      playback.times <-  fromJSON(df$playback.times[[row]])[2:length(fromJSON(df$playback.times[[row]]))] # remove the default original playback
      print(playback.times)
      # plot
      ggplot(prod.df, aes(x=onset, y=pitch, color = error)) +
        theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = target.notes, color = magma.colors[4], size = 2, alpha = 0.7) + 
        geom_vline(xintercept = playback.times, color = magma.colors[5], size = 2, alpha = 0.7) + 
        geom_point() +
        scale_color_manual(values=c(magma.colors[1], magma.colors[2]))
    
    }
    
  }
  
}


# set up WavPlayer
sound::setWavPlayer("./sox/play")


play.seq <- function(midi_notes, length_of_each_note) {
  #print("playing sequence user heard")

  freqs <- midi_to_freq(midi_notes)
  sines <- lapply(freqs, sound::Sine, length_of_each_note)
  
  for (i in seq_along(1:length(sines))) {
    Sys.sleep(length_of_each_note)
    sound::play(cutSampleEnds(sines[[i]])) # cutSampleEnds removes cracks
  }
  
}


play.and.plot.trial <- function(df, row = NULL) {
  
  # if a row isn't specified, randomly select a row
  if (is.null(row)) {
    sampled_trial <- sample(1:nrow(df), 1)
  }
  else {
    sampled_trial <- row
  }
  
  print(paste0("no. trial to plot: ", sampled_trial))

  plot.prod.df(df, sampled_trial)
  play.seq(str.mel.to.vector(df$stimuli.pitch[[sampled_trial]], "-"), 0.25)
  
}

play.and.plot.trial(dat)
```

I can confirm that if I comment out the following line and run play.and.plot.trial(dat), it plots:

```
play.seq(str.mel.to.vector(df$stimuli.pitch[[sampled_trial]], "-"), 0.25)
```

I am not sure why this stops the plotting happening; it only prints to console, I think.

I also tried adding Sys.sleep(5) before the audio playback and this does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

`print` the grob:

```r
play.and.plot.trial <- function(df, row = NULL) {
  # ...
  print(plot.prod.df(df, sampled_trial))
  play.seq(str.mel.to.vector(df$stimuli.pitch[[sampled_trial]], "-"), 0.25)
}
```

### Rationale

Calls to `ggplot(...) + geom_*(...)` do not actually *render* into a graphic device. The rendering is done by `ggplot2:::print.ggplot`. Try this:

```r
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_path()
```

Notice how it does not plot to the viewing pane? Now, if you type in `gg` on the console, it renders. This is because R will try to figure out the most appropriate way to "print" this type of object. Using S3 method dispatch in R, it uses `class(gg)` to look for either `print.gg` (not found) or `print.ggplot` (found within the `ggplot2` package). Since it finds the latter, it uses that.

(If neither were found, it would use `print.default`.)

This is also applicable in `for` loops, where for instance you want to make multiple plots.

The answer in any event is to explicitly render it. Because of the S3 method dispatch, `print(gg)` will still call `ggplot2:::print.ggplot` because of how S3 works.

(If you're ever in a situation where you have a `gg` object that needs rendering but you have not loaded the ggplot2 namespace with `library(ggplot2)`, you can use `ggplot2:::print.ggplot(gg)` explicitly. Or you can use it explicitly just because you want your code to be "declarative" and unambiguous, since *not* knowing how S3 dispatch works might make `print(gg)` look magical.)

Comment: Aha, now I remember running into a similar issue a while ago. Thank you for the very good explanation!